# Grafana Postgres query editor and pg_prometheus (timescaledb)

Tags: postgresql, grafana, prometheus, timescaledb

I have Prometheus writing metrics to Postgres (with TimescaleDB & [pg_prometheus](https://github.com/timescale/pg_prometheus) extensions) throught the prometheus remote_write feature and the [related remote storage adapter](https://github.com/timescale/prometheus-postgresql-adapter). The setup works fine.

I've setup Grafana with the Postgres data source (with the timescaledb option enabled) to evaluate the query editor capabilities. It seems **I cannot manage to do basic "GROUP BY" without switching to the Raw SQL**. The query (which works) is as simple as:

```
SELECT time_bucket('60s',"time") AS time,
       labels#>>'{hostname}' AS hostname,
       avg(value) AS value
FROM metrics
WHERE time > NOW() - interval '1 day' AND
      name = 'host_cpu_usagemhz'
GROUP BY time, hostname
ORDER BY time;
```

I would expect the query editor to provide guidance to the end user to navigate throught the JSONB labels structure but it does not. Worst, the editor gets an eratic behavior as soon as we start grouping on JSONB fields.

Does Grafana just have a poor support of Timescale/pg_prometheus or am I missing something here?

Thanks for your support.